# How to convert loop to apply family function for efficiency?

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column based on if 2 of the already known columns are within a certain distance, I am able to accomplish this with a for loop but there are many rows, so it takes hours to execute. I am having trouble converting this to an apply function to make it more efficient

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Current_Month){
    d = distm(c(90, 90), c(Current_Month$Lon[i], Current_Month$Lat[i]), fun=distHaversine)
    Current_Month$Nearby[i] = ifelse(d < 1000, 1, d)
}
```

Comment: Don't loop over the rows. Also `ifelse` is slow. If you provide a reproducible example people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As markus said:

You don't actually have to loop through your `Current_Month` - data.frame.

The `distm` - function takes also a matrix (or data.frame) with two columns.

This worked for me with a small dummy sample data.

```
Current_Month <- data.frame("Lon" = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                            "Lat" = sample(1:90, 1000, replace = TRUE))

start <- Sys.time() 
d = distm(c(90, 90), Current_Month, fun=distHaversine)
end <- Sys.time()
end - start
> Time difference of 0.001993895 secs

In contrast to your:

start <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:nrow(Current_Month)){
  d = distm(c(90, 90), c(Current_Month$Lon[i], Current_Month$Lat[i]),
      fun=distHaversine)
 }
end <- Sys.time()
end - start
Time difference of 0.2293599 secs
```

So it's considerably faster.

Then proceed:

```
Current_Month$Nearby = t(ifelse(d < 1000, 1, d)) #had to transpose this one though
```

Comment: in the last line where you transpose it I am having trouble, I do the same thing and it works for the first 100k rows, but all the rows after that all the data besides this single column are deleted, any ideas?

Comment: That's weird.. I cannot reproduce your error. I created a `Current_Month` with 200k sample points just like above and it works neatly. You do mean all columns except of `Nearby` are deleted from your `Current_Month`-data.frame, when you surpass 100k rows?